# Dynamically update in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this view:

```
CREATE VIEW vwView
AS
SELECT
         ac.ac_id
        ,ac.Company
        ,ac.no
        ,ac.ContractID
        ,ac.Seller
        ,ac.AcquistionDate
        ,ac.Village
        ,ac.Commune
        ,ac.Area
        ,ac.PlotArea
        ,ac.FieldNo
        ,ac.Topo1
        ,ac.Topo2
        ,ac.Topo3
        ,ac.Topo4
        ,ac.Topo5
        ,ac.TotalAreaSqm
        ,ac.OwnershipTitle
        ,ac.CadastralNO
        ,ac.Type
        ,ac.Price
        ,ac.NotaryCosts
        ,ac.LandTax
        ,ac.OtherTaxes
        ,ac.AgentFee
        ,ac.CadastralFee
        ,ac.TabulationFee
        ,ac.CertSarcini
        ,ac.ProcuraNO
        ,cast((isnull(ac.price,0)+isnull(ac.notarycosts,0)+isnull(ac.landtax,0)+isnull(ac.othertaxes,0)+isnull(ac.agentfee,0)+isnull(ac.cadastralfee,0)+isnull(ac.tabulationfee,0)+isnull(ac.certsarcini,0)) as decimal(12,4)) as TotalCosts
        ,cast((isnull(ac.price,0)+isnull(ac.notarycosts,0)+isnull(ac.landtax,0)+isnull(ac.othertaxes,0)+isnull(ac.agentfee,0)+isnull(ac.cadastralfee,0)+isnull(ac.tabulationfee,0)+isnull(ac.certsarcini,0))/(NULLIF(ac.TotalAreaSqm,0)/10000) as decimal(12,4)) as RonPerHa
        ,cast((isnull(ac.price,0)+isnull(ac.notarycosts,0)+isnull(ac.landtax,0)+isnull(ac.othertaxes,0)+isnull(ac.agentfee,0)+isnull(ac.cadastralfee,0)+isnull(ac.tabulationfee,0)+isnull(ac.certsarcini,0))/(NULLIF(ac.TotalAreaSqm, 0)/10000*NULLIF(ac.FixHist, 0)) as decimal(12,4)) as EurPerHa
        ,ac.DeclImpunere
        ,ac.FixHist
        ,cast((isnull(ac.price,0)+isnull(ac.notarycosts,0)+isnull(ac.landtax,0)+isnull(ac.othertaxes,0)+isnull(ac.agentfee,0)+isnull(ac.cadastralfee,0)+isnull(ac.tabulationfee,0)+isnull(ac.certsarcini,0))/NULLIF(ac.FixHist,0) as decimal(12,4)) as EurHist
        ,ac.LandStatus
        ,ac.Arenda

        ,UPDATE nbAchizitii set ac.Arenda=CASE WHEN ac.PlotArea=ar.PlotArea then 'yes'
                                                                            else 'no'
                                         END
        FROM    nbAchizitii ac
        LEFT JOIN nbArenda ar
        ON
        ac.PlotArea=ar.PlotArea
```

I want to include in my view that update which should act dynamically(it should update each row of ac.Arenda with yes or no) but I don't know how should I place it in the view.
Could someone help me please?

Comment: Are you getting an error currently with above code?

Comment: @bonCodigo Yes i'm getting plenty of errors. If i'm deleting the update, the code is correct but when I'm adding it I get errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to include in my view that update which should act dynamically

You can't do this. You can't `UPDATE` data within the view, the way you did.

However, you can update the underlying data of those tables referenced in the view, i.e., [modifying data through a view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

You have to create your view the same way you did, without the `UPDATE` clause:

```
SELECT
...
FROM your tables
..
```

Then `UPDATE` your view. Something like:

```
UPDATE YourViewName
SET arenda = CASE WHEN PlotArea IS NULL THEN 'no'
                    ELSE 'yes' 
             END;
```

Note that, this method is limited with the limitations and restrictions defined in the section updatable views found in [`CREATE VIEW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) documentation.

---

### Update

In case you want to do this dynamically you have to use triggers, like what you did in your comment like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Arenda_update 
ON nbAchizitii
for update AS 
BEGIN 
  UPDATE ac 
  SET Arenda = CASE 
                  WHEN ac.PlotArea IS NULL then 'no'
                else 'Yes' END
  FROM nbAchizitii ac 
  LEFT JOIN nbArenda ar ON ac.PlotArea = ar.PlotArea
end;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1544a/1)

Comment: I want this update to be dynamically so to not be necessary to run it every time when I want to update that column. How could I do that? Thanks!

Comment: @user1820705 - In this case you have to use triggers, I will update my answer.

Comment: I created this trigger but it's not working, the column it's still null.                                                          'CREATE TRIGGER Arenda_update ON nbAchizitii
for update
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE nbAchizitii
SET Arenda=CASE WHEN ac.PlotArea=ar.PlotArea then 'yes'
                                             else 'no'
                                         END
FROM    nbAchizitii ac
        LEFT JOIN nbArenda ar
        ON
        ac.PlotArea=ar.PlotArea      
END '

Comment: @user1820705 - Sorry for late. It should work fine, see my updated answer.